# how to create personalized latex logo?

Tags: graphics

[image]

Dear Friends, How to create this logo using latex kindly help me

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text}
% tight page
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        % outer circle
            \draw[line width=2 mm,color=DarkMagenta,fill=DarkMagenta!10] circle[radius=7.2 cm];
        % outer text
            \path[
                postaction={
                    decoration={raise=.37ex,
                        text along path,
                        text format delimiters={|}{|},
                        text={%
                            |\Huge\bfseries\color{magenta}|
                             Technical Quality and  Science  Tech Research Publications
                              {\textbullet}
                        },
                        text align=fit to path,
                        reverse path
                    },
                    decorate
                }
            ]
             (0:6.2cm) arc (0:360:6.2cm);
% central text
\node[scale=5,align=center,color=Indigo] at (0, -4){STRP};
\node[color=Brown3] at (0, 1){\includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Harish Thank you for your timely help. But Unfortunately the &  symbol not supporting how to put & symbol

Comment: @user51868 -- the ampersand is a "special" character, which needs to be entered preceded by a backslash, `\&`.  this is basic (la)tex, so you could really benefit from reading some introductory material.  take a look at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/579)